# How to run contact form through xampp

Tags: xampp

So I've created my contact form and to test it out I've been using xampp for my localhost. For some reason no matter what I do, I keep getting the same warning/error every time,

'Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\COH3\contactMail.php on line 13'

This is my code in PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = "********@yahoo.com";
   $headers= "From: ********@yahoo.com";

   if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)){
        echo "All input fields are required";
    } else{
       if(mail($name, $email, $message, $to, $headers)){
            echo "Your message has been sent successfully";
        }else{
            echo "Message failed to send";
        }
   }
}

header("Loction: contact.html");

?>
```

This is the php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = ********@yahoo.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

This is the sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
smtp_port=465
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=********@yahoo.com
auth_password=**********
force_sender=********@yahoo.com
```

What can I possibly get this thing to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message , array|string $additional_headers = [] , string $additional_params = "" ) : bool
```

add_headers is at position 4. In your code. it is at position 5. I think it is a misstake.

The addition of basic headers

```
  <?php
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```